# check change in drop down list every time click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

check change in drop down list every time a button is clicked and my button is an image

**Code:**

```
<select id="dropdown_name">
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
</select>
<img src="images.jpg" class="btn"/>
<script language="javascript">
var com;
    $('#dropdown_name').change(){
            com=$(this).val();
    }
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        alert(com);
         //code
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's the question here? One thing I see right away is that you alert `comp` but you don't have a `comp` variable, only a `com` variable. Also make sure that you fix your syntax for your event binding (you have no closing parenthesis).

Comment: DO you want to bind change event on click of the image ?

Comment: yes its  corrected now @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have lots of error in you code...

```
<script language="javascript">
var com;
$('#dropdown_name').change(function(){ //missing function here
        com=$(this).val();
}) //<---missing bracket here;
$('.btn').click(function(){
    alert(com);
     //code
}); //<-- missing bracet here
</script>
```

from whatever i understood i assum you need this..

try this

```
$(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(){
      alert($('#dropdown_name').val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your script is not valid .. Supposed to look like this

Also there is a typo in the click event .. `comp` is supposed to be `com`

```
var com;
$('#dropdown_name').change(function () {
    com = $(this).val();

}).change();

$('.btn').click(function () {
    alert(com);
    //code
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfuyF/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is . But i am guessing you are trying to 
to bind the change event on click of the image . If that is the case , this will help.

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
   $('#dropdown_name').change(function () {
      alert("changed to : "+ $(this).val());
   });
});
```

Now the change event binded to dropdown_name only after click the event , if the image/.btn is not click you will not get any alert while changing the select

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asDQV/)